# Linear B font problem

Tags: fonts, symbols

I've installed the `archaic` package and I've included `\usepackage{linearb}` in my document. I needed a stick figure symbol so I want to use this package which has a symbol `\BPman` satisfying my needs. But when I use this symbol by command `\textlinb{\BPman}`, an error occurs

`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file linb10): Font linb10 at 720 not found`

How to resolve this?

Comment: You probably didn't do a correct installation. How did you do it?

Comment: miktex admin package manager

Comment: Look whether the file `.../fonts/tfm/public/archaic/linb10.tfm` is present (the dots stand for the main TeX directory). If it is, try refreshing the file name database; otherwise, try redoing the installation.

Comment: did both - didnt work

Comment: OK, so it should be a "map" problem. I'm sure some MiKTeX expert will come to the rescue.

Comment: You probably have a local pdftex.map. If you install fonts in admin mode such local maps are not updated. Check the path of pdftex.map mentioned in your log-file. If it is in your user profile run `updmap` on the command line.

Comment: `updmap` worked!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Mind adding a short answer to clear this from the unanswered list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a local `pdftex.map`. If you install fonts in `admin` mode such local maps are not updated. Check the path of `pdftex.map` mentioned in your log-file. If it is in your user profile run `updmap` on the command line.